# How to populate data from a table, depending upon another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is super straight,

I have a table naming FAQ_MASTER having data of faqs

I have another table naming FAQ_OVERRIDE having data of overrided faqs with foreign key company_id from different table

Now i want to populate data from FAQ_MASTER, if FAQ_OVERRIDE is **not** populating data depending upon the **company_id** fetched from session variable

if FAQ_OVERRIDE is populating data, then populating data from FAQ_MASTER is not required.

i want to run the query in postreSQL

What i have tried  :

```
select 
        * 
    from
        (

            SELECT

            distinct fm.faq_uid as faqUid,

            case 
                when fm.qa_text is not null then fm.qa_text 
                else fm.qa_text 
            end as qaText,
            case 
                when fm.sort_order is not null then fm.sort_order
                else fm.sort_order 
            end as sortOrder,

            fm.end_date as endDate



            FROM rnr.faq_master fm

        ) faq_qry

        left outer join rnr.company_faq_override fo on faq_qry.faqUid = fo.faq_override_uid and fo.mp_company_uid = 734

        WHERE 

        faq_qry.endDate is null 

        AND

        (

        faq_qry.mp_company_uid is null or fo.mp_company_uid = 734

        )   

        ORDER BY 

        faq_qry.sortOrder
```

Comment: Can you give example data and output?

Comment: `case when fm.qa_text is not null then fm.qa_text else fm.qa_text end` what this is supposed to do?

Comment: LEFT JOIN + COALESCE(r.val, l.val) all the way.